# Umbraco7 on saving cancel is giving error

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

While making saveEventArgs.Cancel=true and returning from on saving event of content service is being redirected to #/content/content/edit/0, which is throwing request error in umbraco UI as there is no node with id 0.

Please help in understanding, how can I avoid  umbraco to go to edit 0 id on saving cancel.

Comment: This sounds more like a bug.  Have you seared http://issues.umbraco.org or the forum at http://our.umbraco.org ?

Comment: Seems like a bug but one workaround I found is, on saveEventArgs cancel as true of content services - saving event, is to assign the parentId of the cancelled entity while creating to avoid redirection to 0 node.

Comment: Are you using the content service?  If so, there is a parameter to "not trigger events" when saving.

Comment: Thanks dampee, it is working as expected by setting this raise events param to false.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the specific answer. You call from within your Saving Event Handler the save method on IContentService and set the raise event to false.
E.g.

`sender.Save(content, 0, false);`